# How to hide public from url in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, vue.js, hosting, cpanel, inertiajs

I used Laravel 9 and Inertia.js + Vuejs and the project has been deployed to the cpanel. When I access to the site and it threw an error saying Not Found with code 404 so then I added a new file - .htaccess outside the public folder and the error existed. I tried to access to public folder like this https://imapp.asomaningministries.com/public and it worked but I don't want anyone to  eventually access to this folder. So can I hide it?

Comment: You need to setup your web server pointing has Document Root  /your_web_folder_root/public or us a apache policy in .htaccess file.

Comment: Are you using apache? could you share your vhost setting?

Comment: I run command *ln -s public/ public_html* and still got the error 404. Or can you tell me what command used to set it to the public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set the document root directory as 'public' directory on the domain settings page of cPanel.

---

or you can use .htaccess file like that;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I just copied this rule to the htaccess and it works now. thanks a lot.